# Use JLU's chat room!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, chat

Just saying that I think we need to promote the use of the "Chat" function for everything else that may not be directly suitable for the main question page. It seems our community needs more activity.

Have a question that relates to Japanese but not directly about it?

A point of contention in a question/answer but leaving comments are not suitable?

Want to ask [insert user here] a question about [insert topic here]?

Use the Chat function!

Comment: I'm having trouble logging into the chat room. I know I've done it before, but now it's directing me to make a Stack Exchange account...which I have?

Comment: @silvermaple: The chat system seem to act essentially as it's own stack-exchange site, semi-disconnected from all of the SE sites that are connected to it. It's a bit strange, but I can see why it was done that way.

Comment: @jkerian: I think the problem that I was having was that I couldn't acess it going from meta to chat, but when I'm on the main site, it goes in fine...I couldn't tell you why...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few things you can do to help promote chat usage:

- If you find yourself drawn into a discussion in comments on the main site, suggest continuing the discussion in chat. You can easily insert a link to chat by using `[chat]` in your comment. It will be automatically expanded into a link. e.g. `Let's continue talking about this in [chat].`
- Hang out in chat even when it's deserted.  When someone joins, greet them and strike up a short conversation. Over time, others will do the same and your chat community will grow.
- Consider holding periodic chat events that your community is interested in. For example, our [Home Improvement site](http://diy.stackexchange.com) holds weekly "project update" events where users gather in chat to talk about what DIY projects they're working on and how they're going.

Comment: Yes! These are all things we've tried and found to work on other sites. Even one or two people just conversing casually each day can start to liven up even the deadest of rooms.